# File is created with different owner and I can't delete it Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, permissions, google-drive-api

I created a file and a shortcut in a certain folder in the Drive but for some reason the shortcut was created with a different owner (the owner of the folder) and because of that I can't delete the file (unauthorized).

1. is there a way to let a user delete a file he doesn't own?
2. is there are way to make sure I am the owner of the shortcut I created?

I created both files using the `drive.files.create()` method (wrapped).

```
const resource = {
    parents: [folderId],
    name: title,
    properties: metadata,
  }

const res = await drive.filesInsert({
    resource,
    media: {
      mimeType,
      body,
    },
    fields: 'id, parents'
});

const shortcutMetadata = { ...resource };
    shortcutMetadata.parents = [parent];
    shortcutMetadata.mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut',
    shortcutMetadata.shortcutDetails = {
        targetId: id
      }

const res = await drive.filesInsert({
    resource: shortcutMetadata, fields: 'id, parents'
});
```

and this is the error:

```
{ 
  “reason”: “forbidden”,
  “message”: “Insufficient permissions for this file”
}
```

Comment: Did you create the file on a user's drive or on a shared drive? Can you show your code for the creation of the file?

Comment: So you are the owner of the file while a different user is the owner of the shortcut, but this makes you not auhtorized to delete the file? Please show your complete error message and your request to delete the file, once again please spcify either the file is located on a shared drive.

Comment: @ziganotschka apparently the shortcut is alway owned by the owner of the folder and not the one that created it. I can "fix" this by giving the folder's ownership to the user I'm using for the API actions but I rather have a better solution

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts)

> the shortcut is created on the current user's My Drive and shortcuts are only created for files or folders for which the current user has access.

- Having access does not necessary mean being the owner.

- You can make another user an editor of the file, and in this case this user will be able to make a shortcut on his own drive.
- You can also change the ownership programmatically with [Permissions:Create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create), which in my understanding is what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: in my case the shortcut owner is the folder owner and not the user that created it. why is it happening?

Comment: Maybe because you authenticate as the folder owner when running your code?

Comment: this is what im saying. im not

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly, how do you authenticate your code? As a service account or as a user? If as a user - as which user are you authenticating the execution? As the owner of the file or as the editor whom you would like to become the owner of the shortcut? I suggest you to test your request with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) authenticating as the user whom you would like to be the owner of the shortcut.